# Excel: How to use a changing value in one cell as a range value for another cell

Tags: excel

I'm have been scratching my brain and reading answers on this site diligently but I just can't seem to get the results I am looking for...

Sorry for the confusion, I will try to re-word ...

Columb B is a list of randomly generated numbers (1,6 as in a 6 sided dice)

Cell AJ3 is the number of dice being rolled.

Cell AJ4 is where the total number of true statements in Columb B are to be recorded (in this case the true statement will either be if cell B# is greater than or equal to another number calculated in cell S2 or is cell B# is the letter H

I would like to use the value of cell AJ3 as the range of Columb B in a formula in cell AJ4 that counts either the total number of true numerical values (example B#=S2-1,or B#>=S2) or the total number of the letter "H".

I hope that clearifies things and thank you for your help in the matter!

Comment: This question is difficult to understand as stated. You need to provide a full example of input and output.

Comment: I am a bit confused. Is AJ4 a cell?, is a number to be calculated an written in AJ4, is VBA allowed?

Comment: This edit clarified what you are doing a bit better, however, now there is no actual question. What is it you want?

Comment: Sorry guys/gals, this is my first time using this site to ask a question, I'm a little off the mark haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no clue what you want to do, but maybe this will point you in a direction?

You can use the indirect statement to interpret a string..
as an example:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(C1))
```

will allow you to write the range as a string, in C1. So write B1:B10 in C1, and the sum of the values in B1 to B10 is calculated..

**Update**:

in fact, I was not way off, let me help you along..

To count the H occurrences, in B column you could use:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("B1:B"&AJ3);"H")
```

Now this only needs a long extension for helping you actually do the comparison with a number.. ;)

Comment: I HAVE EDITED MY QUESTION TO TRY TO CLEARIFY MY REQUEST!

Comment: no need to shout, I'll update the answer, when I have something that is closer to what you wan't

Comment: this works in my test sheet..  =COUNTIF(INDIRECT("B1:B"&AJ3);"H")+COUNTIF(INDIRECT("B1:B"&AJ3);">"&S2)

Comment: =COUNTIF(INDIRECT("B1:B"&AJ3);"H")
 This worked great! Thank you very much!